# Firebase / ReactJS - promises not working in the right order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a React beginner and I'm working on a simple CMS app. I have a problem with receiving data from Firebase in the right order. This is a component for editing an existing post or adding a new one. When I open the edit page it launches getPostData function before getUserData (wrong way - pending is set to true and nothing shows up), but when I refresh the edit page everything works fine. Also it works okay when adding a new post. I understand that Firebase works asynchronously, but in my case I need getUserData to receive info before getPostData. At first I had simple callback functions, then I used promises as it is said in [Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html) but that didn't work either. I would really appreciate your help with this.

```
componentDidMount() {
this.getUserData();
}

getPostData = () => {

if (this.props.match.params.id) {

    return firebase.database()
        .ref('/posts/' + this.props.match.params.id)
        .once('value', (snapshot) => {

            const val = snapshot.val();

            this.setState({
                post: val ? val : this.state.post,
                postId: this.props.match.params.id,
                pending: false,
            });
        })
    }
};


getUserData = () => {
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
        this.setState({
            post: {
                username: snapshot.val().username,
                language: snapshot.val().defaultlang,
                uid: user.uid
                //other stuff
            },
            pending: this.props.match.params.id ? true : false
        });
    })
    .then(this.getPostData());
};
```

Comment: setState is also async, have you tried this? `this.setState(yourUserObject, this.getPostData);`.

Comment: Could you please post the entire component code here

Comment: @TarangHirani it's quite long so I put the component code in here: https://jsfiddle.net/ebiedulska/crhde7x0/

Comment: sorry I pasted the wrong code, this is the right link: https://jsfiddle.net/ebiedulska/crhde7x0/6/

Comment: @Kunukn - it worked!! Thanks a lot, I didn't know I can pass a callback function to setState.